# ASP.NET MVC2 Razor - Html.ActionLink with HTML Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

please help,

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.good_id},DBNull.Value,new With { @title="Edit", @rel="gb_page[500, 500]"})%>
```

I want to add html attributes in my actionlink, but it doesnt work with these error:
Expression Expected

thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't use Razor in MVC2.  Second, you seem to be using WebForms View Engine, so even if Razor was usable you can't mix razor with WebForms.  Third, you shouldn't be using DBNull.. You probably don't need that field at all, but if you do then it should be `Nothing` (in VB) or `null` in C#.

What you want is something like this (c# syntax, i don't know the vb way, and I assume gb_page is some kind of array?):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.good_id , title="Edit", 
      rel=gb_page[500, 500]}) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried your suggestion but without character '@' before html attribute, compiler give error response told  it was anonymous.. like this : <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new With{ @id = item.good_id , @title="Edit", @rel="gb_page[500, 500]"}) %>  it almost complete but still error, it told 'Expression expected'. please help..