# How would I translate this html into razor?

Tags: html, razor

I want to replicate the following html using razor syntax:

```
<a href="index.html" data-description="I Want This Description">Home</a>
```

I know I would do this for the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
```

How would I add the information that is within the html tag above "data-description="I Want This Description""  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC2 Razor - Html.ActionLink with HTML Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962477/asp-net-mvc2-razor-html-actionlink-with-html-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add html attributes by adding a parameter containing an anonymous object which contains the attributes and values you want.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { data_description = "I want this desription" })
```

Note the underscore instead of the hyphen. MVC automatically replaces the underscores with hyphens when the view is displayed.